# redefinition of a class

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

I have defined in my header file the class below:

```
class mtp_wrapper
{
private:
    LIBMTP_raw_device_t * usbrawdevice;
    int numusbrawdevice;
    LIBMTP_error_number_t err;
    LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *dev;

public:
    mtp_wrapper() {
        dev = NULL;
    };
    void setDevice(LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *dev);
    LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *getDevice();
};
```

and in the c++ part is :

```
mtp_wrapper::mtp_wrapper()
{
 .... <some code>
} 


void mtp_wrapper::setDevice(LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *dev) {
    this->dev = dev;
}

LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t * mtp_wrapper::getDevice() {
    return dev;
}
```

By the way, when building I got an issue saying that mtp_wrapper is already defined but I need to make sure that the dev variable is initialised at NULL.

In 99% of examples, I saw people using this and it seems working in their cases

Comment: You have already defined the constructor in the class body. `mtp_wrapper() { dev = NULL; };`

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the .h file

```
class mtp_wrapper
{
private:
    LIBMTP_raw_device_t * usbrawdevice;
    int numusbrawdevice;
    LIBMTP_error_number_t err;
    LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *dev;

public:
    mtp_wrapper();
    void setDevice(LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *dev);
    LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *getDevice();
};
```

and this in the cpp

```
mtp_wrapper::mtp_wrapper() : dev(NULL)
{
 .... <some code>
} 


void mtp_wrapper::setDevice(LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *dev) {
    this->dev = dev;
}

LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t * mtp_wrapper::getDevice() {
    return dev;
}
```

You have defined twice the constructor, once in the header and once in the cpp. However if you want to make sure that the def variable is NULL put the : dev( NULL )

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you defined your  mtp_wrapper()  constructor twice: once in the header file and second time in your cpp file. Just merge both implementations and write in the .cpp file:

```
mtp_wrapper::mtp_wrapper()
{
    dev = NULL;
 .... <some code>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mtp_wrapper() is defined in the header file and you are trying to define it in implementation file (.cpp) file.
Quick Fix : declare mtp_wrapper() in header as mtp_wrapper();

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error message because you defined the default constructor here:

```
mtp_wrapper() {
    dev = NULL;
};
```

and here again:

```
mtp_wrapper::mtp_wrapper()
{
 .... <some code>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is first definition in .h file

```
mtp_wrapper() {
    dev = NULL;
};
```

and below one is second definition in .cpp file:-

```
mtp_wrapper::mtp_wrapper()
{
 .... <some code>
}
```

for which compiler is crying